# Invalid Block Tag i=0, in Django

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

I was going through Appengine's Getting Started guide for python, while reading up [templates](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstarted/templates.html),I modified the code(which is a simple guestbook) to include simple numbering next to the guestbook entries.

In index.html i added the (what I thought would be) relevant code.

**index.html (I have added {%i=0%} on line 3,{%i+=1%} on line 5, and {{i}} on line 7, the rest is from the guide):**

```
<html>
  <body>
    {%i=0%}
 {% for greeting in greetings %}
    {%i+=1%}
   {% if greeting.author %}
        <b>{{i}}:{{ greeting.author.nickname }}</b> wrote:
      {% else %}
       An anonymous person wrote:
      {% endif %}
      <blockquote>{{ greeting.content|escape }}</blockquote>
    {% endfor %}

    <form action="/sign" method="post">
      <div><textarea name="content" rows="3" cols="60"></textarea></div>
      <div><input type="submit" value="Sign Guestbook"></div>
    </form>

    <a href="{{ url }}">{{ url_linktext }}</a>

  </body>
</html>
```

I got the following error

> TemplateSyntaxError: Invalid block
>   tag: 'i=0'

I read up Django's help on [templates](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/), which says that

> The Django template system provides
>   tags which function similarly to some
>   programming constructs – an if tag for
>   boolean tests, a for tag for looping,
>   etc. – but these are not simply
>   executed as the corresponding Python
>   code, and the template system will not
>   execute arbitrary Python expressions.

So I guess, that performing calculations is not what the templating system is for.

***tl;dr***

**Can anyone tell me how to number my entries or use the "counter - increment" construct using Django templates?**

I don't thing this code is necessary, but to complete the picture,

**Unchanged helloworld.py code:**

```
import os
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import template
import cgi

from google.appengine.api import users
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app
from google.appengine.ext import db

class Greeting(db.Model):
    author = db.UserProperty()
    content = db.StringProperty(multiline=True)
    date = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)

class MainPage(webapp.RequestHandler):
def get(self):
    greetings_query = Greeting.all().order('-date')
    greetings = greetings_query.fetch(10)

    if users.get_current_user():
        url = users.create_logout_url(self.request.uri)
        url_linktext = 'Logout'
    else:
        url = users.create_login_url(self.request.uri)
        url_linktext = 'Login'

    template_values = {
        'greetings': greetings,
        'url': url,
        'url_linktext': url_linktext,
        }

    path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'index.html')
    self.response.out.write(template.render(path, template_values))
class Guestbook(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        greeting = Greeting()

        if users.get_current_user():
            greeting.author = users.get_current_user()

        greeting.content = self.request.get('content')
        greeting.put()
        self.redirect('/')

application = webapp.WSGIApplication(
                                     [('/', MainPage),
                                      ('/sign', Guestbook)],
                                     debug=True)

def main():
    run_wsgi_app(application)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what you need it for. If you need the actual count, you can use a for loop in the template: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#for

Then you can use *forloop.counter* or *forloop.counter0* to check the index.

If you just want to display a list of numbers you can use a html ordered list.

Django's template engine is for design only, and you want to keep calculations out of it. If you need to do something with your data at the template layer you can write a [custom tag/filter](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/).

Comment: thanks. is there a way to do some simple calculations in the templating system? or is it purely for presentation?btw that works.

Comment: Django's template system is, by design, presentation only. Though it is possible to write custom tags and filters that do other things.

Comment: If you want a numbered list, use <ol> and <li> tags.

Answer (score 2):

From http://www.djangobook.com/en/beta/chapter04/

```
{% for item in todo_list %}
    <p>{{ forloop.counter }}: {{ item }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```